# Scan HTML DOM elements from the webpage and their properties using Selenium WebDriver/Javascript/Java

Tags: java, html, dom, selenium

Scenario: Google home page has 1 input field.However my program below displays 3 alerts.
I am struggling to filter the visible element(textbox) on any web page.Need your help pls?
eventually,I wish to retrieve its properties.

Language: Java/Javascript/Selenium APIs.

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        System.out.println(js.executeScript("return document.title"));
        js.executeScript("var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');"+
        "for(var x=0;x<allInputs.length;x++){"+
        "if(allInputs[x].type == 'text'){" +
        "alert(x)"+
        "}"+
        "}");
```

Comment: Please improve your question. For now it looks like "*do this for me*" instead of "*I tried to solve it this way, but I am stuck because of (and here you describe your problem)*".

Comment: Thanks Pshemo,I didn't know the rule of the game.This is my first post.Will do that now onwards.

Comment: Here are the rules of the game http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No problem. Just use [edit] button under your post to provide more details about problem you are facing.

Comment: if anyone could change the status from 'on hold' to active pls

Comment: Why are you using the `JavascriptExecutor`? The `Webdriver` api will allow you to find the input element by `Webelement input = driver.findElement(By.Id("q"));`

Comment: Mark,I would like to create one generic function that would count the no. of objects eg. textbox,link etc displayed on the webpage and collect it's atributes.Using webdriver i need to explicitly key in the locators and hence it's difficult to make it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it returns more than one is because there are several input elements on the page.  submit, checkbox, and hidden are also types of input elements.

If you just want text fields, try changing your JS to:

```
    js.executeScript("var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');"+
    "for(var x=0;x<allInputs.length;x++){"+
    "if(allInputs[x].type == 'text'){" +
    "alert(x)"+
    "}"+
    "}");
```